# Renaming folders, files and subfolders in bash

Tags: file, bash, directory, renaming

I have a problem with a bash script...
I want to rename all files, folders and subfolders in a recursive manner, from
lower-case to upper-case (or viceversa).
I've wrote this script, but it doesn't work.

```
find . -depth -iname \* -exec mv {} `echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` \;
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple while-loop:

```
find testdir/ -depth | while read file; do NEWNAME=$(dirname "$file")/$(echo $(basename "$file") | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'); mv "$file" "$NEWNAME"; done
```

Comment: I've tried to use your first script, but it only changes the first "level" of the folder tree. If I have, for example, DocumentsFolder-JobFolder-Test.txt, after the execution I have DOCUMENTFOLDER-JobFolder-Test.txt. I want the uppercase for all folders, subfolders and files, like DOCUMENTFOLDER-JOBFOLDER-TEST.TXT.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your command in backticks, `echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`, gets expanded by the shell first, so what `find` actually sees as arguments are

```
find . -depth -iname \* -exec mv {} {} \;
```

(Running `tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` on the input `{}` just gives you `{}` right back again).

Here's one workaround, using a subshell as the `-exec` command:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -iname \* -exec \
    sh -c 'mv "$0" "`tr \[:upper:\] \[:lower:\] <<<"$0"`"' {}  \;
```

or more readably, using $() syntax:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -iname \* -exec \
    sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<<$0)"' {}  \;
```

Note that you also need to quote the `tr` character ranges to stop the shell expanding them!

It's also a good idea to add the `-mindepth 1` so you don't get an error from trying to run `mv . .`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ... I tried to run the script but I get a lot of syntax errors and no changes within folder subfolder and file names

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer by other means, but for the record the original code didn't work properly on filenames with spaces, which might be the problem. I've corrected it now. Once you get up to this many quoting levels the loop solution starts to look pretty good, indeed ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what does <<<$0 mean?

Comment: `<<<` in bash creates a "here string", meaning that whatever word follows becomes the standard input of the command, just as `some-command <some-file` makes the contents of `some-file` the standard input). For example, try `tr a-z A-Z <<<"a test string"`. In this case, `<<<$0` takes the first argument, `$0`, to `sh -c ...` -- the filename that `find` passes in by substituting `{}` -- and makes it the input for `tr ...`. (BTW, in general the first argument to a script is `$1`, but `sh -c` behaves differently -- see the Bash manual).